# Calendário no Android

Tags: android

Ola pessoal eu sou novo por aqui e me perdoem por alguma imaturidade na área de programação para Android. O negocio é o seguinte eu estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que precisa pegar uma data, então minha ideia é um especie de botão onde ele abra um calendário (atual) e a pessoa possa escolher um dia igual o "Jcalendar" do java, não sei se da pra entender a minha pergunta mas fico no aguardo das respostas....
Desde já agradeço por tudo...

Comment: Seja bem vindo, recomendo fazer um [tour], e editar sua questão para não ser fechada como ampla demais, boa sorte.

Comment: Jorge por aqui o pessoal gosta que você poste o que exatamente você já fez e mostre especificamente seu problema. Uma pergunta ampla assim não é muito bem aceita, não passa uma boa impressão. Aliás uma pergunta ampla assim o google responde sem problemas:
https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=calendar+android+example&*

Comment: Muito obrigado pela informação... é culpa da inexperiência ainda estou me adaptando as perguntas ...

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é o que você precisa, mas também tive que trabalhar com calendário e achei esse biblioteca muito boa:

https://github.com/shrikanth7698/Collapsible-Calendar-View-Android

```
final CollapsibleCalendar collapsibleCalendar = findViewById(R.id.calendarView);

collapsibleCalendar.setCalendarListener(new CollapsibleCalendar.CalendarListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDaySelect() {
        Day day = viewCalendar.getSelectedDay();
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "Selected Day: "
                + day.getYear() + "/" + (day.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + day.getDay());
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDataUpdate() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMonthChange() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onWeekChange(int i) {

    }
});
```

Comment: @Barbetta resposta alterada

Answer (score 0):

Eu desenvolvi uma tela parecida uma vez. O layout pode ser o que você imaginar. segue a baixa os metodos que fiz para chamar o calendario do android e capturar a data selecionada pelo usuario num edit.

```
edt_data = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_data);
bCalendario= (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_calendario);
bCalendario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()   {
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  public void onClick(View v)  {
    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID); //chamar o calendario
  }
});

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID: return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener,mYear, mMonth-1, mDay);
  }
  return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
  public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    mYear = year;
    mMonth = monthOfYear;
    mDay = dayOfMonth;
    updateDisplay();
  }
};

private void updateDisplay() {
        edt_data.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(mDay).append("/")
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("/")
                .append(mYear).append(" "));
    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta e atenção dos colegas... estarei fazendo os testes e publicarei o resultado em breve...;)

Comment: Queria só tirar mais uma duvida: Como declara o "DATE_DIALOG_ID"

Comment: é uma variavel Integer